# When are tenure-track positions in the social sciences usually announced in Canada?

Tags: job-search, tenure-track, canada

I am ABD (All but Dissertation), and I want to start applying for TT jobs in my field. Probably for Fall 2024 or Winter 2025. When are these advertised?

Answer (score 1):

There’s no uniform date although the plurality of ads get out in early Fall closing in December or early January. However some schools will advertise as late as April for a September start.